# Unable to pass HTML and CSS in web URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am working on a CodeIgniter based website. When I try to pass HTML/CSS in web URL it redirect to 404 page. For example, if the URL is http://geeksdemy.com/html , it goes to 404 page.
It is a EduTech website, and due to above mentioned reasons, admin is unable to upload courses for HTML and CSS.
Please help if anyone know the solution.

Thanks for your forthcoming response.

Comment: check your `.htaccess ` and in `routes.php` whether default controller set or not.

Comment: Can you re edit your question and place the head tags where your css links are.

Comment: Thanks for your response....
Actually I have VPS hosting... so using web.config instead of .htaccess...
And I got the issue... It is with URL rewrite definition..
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|mp4|woff|woff2|pdf" negate="true" />
</conditions>
All the names passed in pattern, can not be passed in URL...

But I am far way from the solution...Waiting for responses...

Answer (score 1):

Your page is available over

`http://geeksdemy.com/?html`

I would assume that solution in `.htaccess` file could be changing file line from this

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

to this

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`.

Now, since are using IIS (correct?), maybe it would be working if you make similar in Rewrite action or url match of `web.config` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am using web.config file and found the issue. It was in web.config file.